# Shell Save the array element values in the variables

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, shell-script

I need to copy the files from one folder to another, here source and destination information are in the text file.

File content: res.txt

/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android\ Gradle\ test\ build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/logo_splash.png=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android\ Gradle\ test\ build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable/logo_splash.png

Here I am trying to split the string with the delimiter "=" and assigning it to the respective variables. And, need to trigger the copy command.

To accomplish the above, I am trying to split the string into an array and assigning the array index element value to the local variables

```
lines=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android\ Gradle\ test\ build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/logo_splash.png=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android\ Gradle\ test\ build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable/logo_splash.png
SOURCE=""
DEST=""
echo $lines | awk '{split($0,numbers,"=")} END {
for(n in numbers){
   if (n == 1) { 
      SOURCE = ${numbers[1]}
   }
   else if (n == 2) {
      DEST= ${numbers[2]}
   }
}}'
echo ${numbers[1]}
echo ${numbers[2]}
```

getting error as

```
awk: {split($0,numbers,"=")} END {for(n in numbers){ SOURCE = ${numbers[1]}}
awk:                                                           ^ syntax error
```

and for echo Getting output as

```
+ echo

+ echo
```

@Gombai Sandor, I have changed the above as suggested by you and it works.

```
SOURCE=$(echo $lines | awk -F= '{print $1}')
echo "source is " $SOURCE
DESTINATION=$(echo $lines | awk -F= '{print $2}')
echo "destination is " $DESTINATION
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing shell's `if [...] ... elif [...] ... fi` syntax into awk's code. 
awk would use

```
if (...) {
   ...
} else if (...) {
   ...
}
```

in this context.

In addition, you expect awk's array to appear in awk's parent shell here

```
echo ${numbers[1]}
echo ${numbers[2]}
```

This will not happen. You can write strings in awk and parse that output on in the shell put awk (or any other program) will not mangle its calling environment.

Where the syntax error is indicated is another mixture:

```
${numbers[1]}
```

is a bash array element reference... in an awk code (it almost has some meaning to awk but I suggest not forcing this).

I would recommend describing WHAT exactly your task is and asking for hints because HOW you wish to solve it here and explaining why it won't work will be a bit long.
But first of all you should digest the thing that shell (and its language) is one thing and awk (and its language) running inside it is another. They have similar elements but that is ONLY similarity.

Just to split a string into two parts if they are connected via a single character is pretty easy and does not require awk. cut is the basic splitting program.

```
SOURCE=$(echo $lines | cut -f1 -d=)
```

will put the first field into SOURCE where fields are separated by = in the input of **cut**
Ocasionally, you can come across codes like,

```
SOURCE=$(echo $lines | awk -F= '{print $1}')
```

which is the same.
DEST can be assigned similarly with both methods but targeting the second field.

Comment: awk does not use "then" but it expects {} around command blocks of if/else if they contain more than one command

Comment: Thanks, more description added for the exact requirement

Comment: Thanks It works. I stuck in this for more than hours,  you saved my time.

Comment: Glad to help. Have fun with it!

Comment: cp -f /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android\ Gradle\ test\ build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/logo_splash.png  /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Android\ Gradle\ test\ build/workspace/MainApp/app/src/main/res/drawable/logo_splash.png

    Previously I tried to read the above line from file and execute the command, but always getting the error "line 21: /src/main/res/drawable/logo_splash.png: No such file or directory"